# Прогнозирование погоды с помощью алгоритма классификации KNN

Tags: машинное-обучение, инспекция-кода, классификация

Задача о прогнозировании является достаточно трудоемкой и ее можно решать различными способами. Я решил воспользоваться методами машинного обучения и использовать алгоритм K ближайших соседей для своего [кода](https://nbviewer.org/github/MStan123/Weather-Prediction/blob/main/KNN.ipynb#)
.

После обучения модели ее точность оказалась примерно 87%(неплохо так). Во время тестирования модели сделал нормализацию и ввел данные, от которых зависит погода.
Если правильно понимаю я должен был получить результат того какая будет погода, но получаю `array(2023)`. Не понимаю что не так.

Подскажите пожалуйста и по возможности покритикуйте реализацию решения самой задачи.

данные для погоды брал [отсюда](https://www.visualcrossing.com/weather/weather-data-services).

Comment: На какой срок прогноз с точностью 87%? Если на один день, то интересно, какова окажется точность тупого метода линейной регрессии (смотрим вчера и сегодня -- проводим прямую - получаем прогноз на завтра)

Comment: @avp Не удивлюсь, что с погодой как с ценой акций лучший прогноз на завтра будет такая же погода как сегодня )

Comment: @avp ахах, регрессию тоже планировал проверить. А датасет о погоде был взят с марта прошлого года до 19 марта этого года.

Comment: @Stan Только учтите, что для процессов, развивающихся во времени, нельзя пользоваться "послезнанием". Нельзя предсказывать погоду на сегодня, зная погоду на завтра. То есть нужно разбираться, какие данные и как вы используете, чтобы не допускать такой "утечки данных", которой у вас не будет доступно, когда вы реальный прогноз строить начнёте. Это вообще на будущее общий совет, имейте в виду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
X = df.iloc[:,:-1].values 
Y = df.iloc[:,-1:].values
```

> Если правильно понимаю я должен был получить результат того какая будет погода, но получаю `array(2023)`

Последняя колонка в вашем датафрейме - это год `year`. Этим кодом вы из `X` выкидываете последнюю колонку, а в `Y` наоборот берёте только эту колонку. Конечно, вы в качестве предсказания получаете год, к которому относятся данные с прогнозом. 2023 - это год, всё правильно.

Получать `X` и `Y` для предсказания конкретной колонки датафрейма лучше так:

```py
X = df.drop(columns='conditions').values
Y = df['conditions'].values
```

Вот теперь вы строите модель для предсказания погодных условий `conditions`. В числовом виде. Чтобы получить результат "человекочитаемом" виде вам нужно либо расшифровать получаемое число обратно через `LabelEncoder`, либо просто и не применять вообще `LabelEncoder` при обработке данных. Для `KNN` классификатора это не нужная операция, если речь идёт о целевой переменной.

Comment: На самом деле, сам был удивлен, что испольщуя классификацию грейдер жалуется на стринг значения, поэтому был вынужден использовать энкодинг, но теперь понял, что у меня неверно были подобраны X и Y. Спасибо за объяснение!